# How to remove text from browser title?

Tags: nodes

I'm looking for a way to change the text ' | Drupal' part from the  tag for all pages to ' | ToAnyThing'. I guess it should be possible to achieve this in the admin interface somewhere, but I cannot find where.

Thanks.

Comment: By default Drupal attaches the site name. You can change the site name in the basic site settings or use the module Metatag to get more options.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems somewhat off-topic as you don't know what this thing is and how to generally change that, independent from Drupal, and I'd recommend to find that out first.

But to take a shortcut from here: that's the so called meta title. And you'll be able to customize it pretty heavily by using [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag).

> The Metatag module allows you to automatically provide structured
>   metadata, aka "meta tags", about a website. In the context of search
>   engine optimization, when people refer to meta tags they are usually
>   referring to the meta description tag and the meta keywords tag that
>   may help improve the rankings and display of a site in search engine
>   results. In addition, the module provides support for meta tags (Open
>   Graph Protocol from Facebook, Twitter Cards from Twitter) that allow
>   control of how content appears when shared on social networks.